# invalid column name search error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express

I am trying to get search query
Its in asp.net c# please help me for search query.

```
protected void btnreg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string search = query.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE  search LIKE '%' + nor + '%' OR recipe LIKE '%' + search + '%'  OR ingredients LIKE '%' + search + '%'  OR type_of_food LIKE '%' + search + '%' OR type_of_meal LIKE '%' + search + '%' ", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    repeter.DataSource = dt;
    repeter.DataBind();
    }}
```

Comment: I can see one problem `WHERE nor` may be a typo, but just check it again, cause I think you need a NOT there. Also where is the column name? YOu cannot write WHERE NOT LIKE 'something'. It should be Where COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE  '%SOMEVALUE%'

Comment: What columns does your `recipe` table have?

Comment: where is the declaration of `nor`?

Comment: nor, recipe, type_of_food, type_of_meal are cloumns of my table recipe

Comment: @user3363485, `ingredients` as well? And are you sure `search LIKE '%' + nor + '%'` should not be otherwise?

Comment: i have tried geting it reversed bust same erorr

Comment: Ahhhhh! try using a SqlCommand Object and add the search as parameter to your query.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose 'nor' is a column name in your table .. try the following :-

```
protected void btnreg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string search = query.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE  nor LIKE '%'" + search + "'%' OR recipe LIKE '%' "+ search + "'%'  OR ingredients LIKE '%' "+ search + "'%'  OR type_of_food LIKE '%' "+ search + "'%' OR type_of_meal LIKE '%' "+ search +" '%' ", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    repeter.DataSource = dt;
    repeter.DataBind();

}
}
```

Actually you cannot enclose the varibale search inside the "double quotes" tag .
Hope this helps you .

Cheers !

Comment: now i get error of incorrect syntax of what i searched

Comment: I guess you gotta try your stuff with those quotes and double quotes

Comment: @BitingBugz : [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)!!

Comment: can you give me one example for search queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Parameterized Queries !

E.g

```
var command = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE  recipe LIKE '% @Receipe %'";

var cmd= new SqlCommand(command , yourconnetion);

cmd.Parameters["@Receipe "].Value =query.Text;
```

OR

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Receipe ",query.Text);
```

Read more about [How and Why to Use Parameterized Queries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the right one, it goes like this.
Although thanks for help guys.

```
protected void btnreg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE  nor LIKE '%" + query.Text + "%' OR recipe LIKE '%" + query.Text + "%'  OR ingredients LIKE '%" + query.Text + "%'  OR type_of_food LIKE '%" + query.Text + "%' OR type_of_meal LIKE '%" + query.Text + "%' ", con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    repeter.DataSource = dt;
    repeter.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use `Parametarized` and `Using{}` statement to auto dispose and close connection


using( SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\19-02\ABCC\App_Data\abcc.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
            {
                    objConnection.Open();

                    try
                    {

                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE  nor LIKE '% @query %'" , con))
                       DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query",query.Text); 
                       da.Fill(dt);


                    }
                    catch(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }



                }
```